# Is it possible to combine MultiGet with a Bool query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

The MultiGet api can be used to fetch multiple documents based on given ids. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html)

Is it possible to add more filters to this operation? Given a list of ids, I only want to find the documents for which 'color' = 'green'.

### Example:

Let's say the following documents exist:

- Doc 1: {"id": "1", "color": "green" }
- Doc 2: {"id": "2", "color": "red" }
- Doc 3: {"id": "3", "color":  "green"}
- Doc 4: {"id": "4", "color":  "green"}

#### Goal:

Get documents with ids **1, 2 or 4**, for which the color is "**Green**".

#### Expected result:

[Doc 1, Doc 4]

#### The query so far...:

```
GET /_mget
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_index": "my-index-000001",
      "_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "_index": "my-index-000001",
      "_id": "2"
    },
    {
      "_index": "my-index-000001",
      "_id": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

or using NEST in C#:

```
var ids = new List<string> {"1", "2", "4"};
var result = await _elasticClient
   .MultiGetAsync(s => s
                    .Index("my-index-000001")
                    .GetMany<SomeRecordObject>(ids)
                );
```

So I'm actually looking for a way to add a Bool query to the MultiGet query (I think). Anyone who can point me towards the right direction?

Comment: In the multiget you cant, i thinck you could add a postfilter.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-post-filter.html

Comment: looks like you want to do a search query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multi get is only for getting multiple documents by id. If you need to perform querying or filtering, then a search query is needed.

Note that multi get and search have different behaviour when it comes to *just* indexed documents. With multi get, a *just* indexed document can be immediately retrieved using its id. With search however, a document will only appear in search results once the index is refreshed ([refresh interval elapses (by default, 1 second)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-modules.html#index-refresh-interval-setting) or [index is manually refreshed with the refresh API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-refresh.html)).